# What to include in .htaccess using ISAPI_Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, iis, isapi-rewrite

So im trying to configure caching options in a .htacces file. Problem is im on a windows server using IIS, but my hosting provider has installed ISAPI_Rewrite to work around this. My question Is there anything different in the htaccess file i need to include thats not 'normally' there to make this work properly ? And can i just start from scratch in my text editor, create the file, and upload it (assuming rewrites enabled on the server) ? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISAPI_Rewrite from Helicon is simply mod_rewrite in Apache equivalent. In order to use caching you'd need HeliconApe, which includes ISAPI_Rewrite functionality along with all the bells and whistles of Apache. Make sure your provider has HeliconApe, not just ISAPI_Rewrite3.

Yes, you can make a file from scratch, but I'd suggest referring to their official site for correct syntax.